# Get Queryset by removing White spaces in the middle of the string - Django

Tags: python, django

I am having table which has column "name". I want to get record by providing name, which contains extra white spaces in middle.

```
my table looks like as follows.
id     name
 1     Raj Kumar
 2     Praveen Kumar
 3     Sandya
```

My Table contain records in which row contain only one spaces at the middle. I want to make a query as follows.

```
input_name = 'Raj  Kumar'(Which contain two spaces)
a = A.objects.get(name=input_name)
```

The above will return "None". Kindly help me out to solve the problem.

Comment: see the duplicate - and specially the second part or Daniel Roseman's answer - for the correct solution (which is to store a normalized version of 'name' along the submitted one and use the same normalization on the input).

Answer (score 1):

if the there is only one condition(two spaces in between) then you can just replace two spaces with one space like below

```
input_name = 'Raj  Kumar'(Which contain two spaces)
a = A.objects.get(name=input_name.replace("  "," "))
```

Comment: Namaware has posted a perfect solution for all cases where there are more then a single space between the words

Comment: @ShubhamPaliwal Namaware solution is far from perfect actually - what if it's the db values that contains duplicated spaces ?

Comment: Though the answer provided by @Daniel Roseman is worth referencing but Mohamed specifically specified that the error he is encountering is at the time of user input.